# How to identify if the given day, month, and year, combine a legal date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date

Given 3 numbers: DD, MM, YYYY, what is the easiest way to know if they combine a legal date ?

Examples:

```
14, 05, 2011     =>     Legal
29, 02, 2011     =>     Illegal
29, 02, 2012     =>     Legal
35, 11, 1989     =>     Illegal
14, 18, 2011     =>     Illegal
14, 00, 2011     =>     Illegal
00, 11, 1979     =>     Illegal
31, 11, 1979     =>     Illegal
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `valid_date?` But it's `YYYY, MM, DD`:

```
irb(main):015:0> require 'date'
=> true
irb(main):021:0> Date::valid_date?(2011,05,14)
=> true
irb(main):022:0> Date::valid_date?(2011,02,29)
=> false
irb(main):023:0> Date::valid_date?(2012,02,29)
=> true
```

Comment: I couldn't find a documentation for `valid_date?`. Could you share a pointer ?

Comment: Actually, it's `valid_civil?` in many docs - http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#M001222 But `valid_civil?` it's an alias to `valid_date?`

Answer (score 4):

Date has a method valid_civil? .

```
require 'date'
dates = DATA.readlines.map{|line| line.split(', ').map(&:to_i)}
dates.each do |date|
  d, m, y = date
  puts Date.valid_civil?(y, m, d)
end

__END__
14, 05, 2011
29, 02, 2011
29, 02, 2012
35, 11, 1989
14, 18, 2011
14, 00, 2011
00, 11, 1979
31, 11, 1979
```

Comment: For those wondering, this is the 'official', documented name, while `valid_date?` is an alias to this method.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use something like:

```
require 'time'

def valid(year,month,day)
   Time.parse "#{year}#{month}#{day}" rescue return false
   return true
end
```